# How can I inspect or query a Yup Schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am creating a form library using React + Material UI + react-hook-form + yup. One of the parameters of my component is a yup schema to validate the form values.

Depending on the yup schema definition, I would like to draw the form components.

```
const schema = yup.object({
  example: yup.string(),
  exampleRequired: yup.string().required(),
};
```

How can I query the schema to know which field is required? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the describe() method in yup schemas.  You should be able to look up the necessary metadata using `schema.describe().fields['exampleRequired']`.  More information here: https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemadescribeoptions-resolveoptions-schemadescription